# How to stream from an input file into a conduit that has a state

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, state-monad, conduit, io-monad

I want to use conduit for reading from a file and then stream it into a tokenizer. The culprit is, that even the same sequence of chars might produce different tokens depending on previous input.

So how can I handle `State` in a single `Conduit` inbetween a bunch of `IO` ones?

Just writing `Conduit Char (State TokenizerStateType) Token` does yield several errors of wrong types (IO wanted, State got type of errors).

Since I am not at my own computer I can't provide an not-working-minimal-example, but I will add one as soon as I have ghc available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend using a `Conduit Char (StateT TokenizerStateType IO)`, and using `liftIO` as necessary to perform `IO` actions.

Comment: OK, I had to warp it in an additional `ResourceT` but it works now. So the type is now `Conduit Char (ResourceT (StateT TokenizerStateType IO)) Token`